# Ruby on rails 5; How to stop installing gem related files when I bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I was making a chat app with ruby on rails 5.
I tried to implement image sending function in my app.
I followed the instruction of the below blog.(sorry in Japanese)

http://yamakichi.hatenablog.com/entry/2017/01/18/232856

1) bundleinstall below gems

```
    gem "carrierwave"    
    gem "piet"    
    gem "mini_magick"
```

2) Create uploader

But it didn't work.
I removed gem "piet" by bundle upload after I deleted it.

At this moment, I realized that about 8000 unknown files were installed.

Below are examples of the file names installed.

```
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bin/rake  
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/cache/concurrent-ruby-1.0.5.gem  
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.0.5/lib/concurrent/hash.rb  
....
```

All the files start with `"vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0".`

If I delete this `"vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0"` file, I can remove every unnecessary files.

But next, I couldn't turn on local server.

It said,

"Could not find rake-12.1.0 in any of the sources"
"Run `bundle install` to install missing gems."

And if I bundleinstall, this 8000 file were installed again.

How can I avoid this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gem `piet` may be a dependency of another gem in your Rails project. When in doubt you can delete your copy of `Gemfile.lock` and run `bundle` again. It will auto-generate a new copy with the correct dependencies.

If you're working on a Rails project, it's totally normal for ~8,000 files to be installed since Rails itself relies on quite a few gems.

One way to cut down on the number of files installed by bundler is to skip the documentation within each gem. That can be accomplished by adding this to your local ~/.gemrc file

```
gem: --no-document
```

Comment: My mentor told me exactly the same thing.  It is normal for ~ 8000 files to be installed.  So I gitignored these files.  Thank you for answering my question.